# Can I force a Drools rule to match all objects of a type instead of just one

Tags: drools

I have a business rule that I need to model in Drools. The rule states that I have a set of trains going on journeys. I need the rule to fire if every train matches the following criteria:

- The driver's name is Ted
- OR the driver's name is Joe and he's going to a station in Scotland
- OR the driver's name is Andy and he's going from London to Birmingham

I can write a rule that matches if any of the trains matches the above criteria, e.g.

`Train(driver == "Ted" 
      || (driver == "Joe" && destCountry == "Scotland") 
      || (driver == "Andy" && origin == "London" && dest == "Birmingham"))`

But can I write a rule that ensures ALL the trains in the knowledge base match the criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple: you use the conditional element `not` which implements the *negated existential quantifier* ∄. Of course, you must ascertain the absence of the negated condition, i.e.

```
not Train( ! (driver == "Ted") 
         && ! (driver == "Joe" && destCountry == "Scotland") 
         && ! (driver == "Andy" && origin == "London" && dest == "Birmingham"))
```

Comment: This seems kind of obvious, but somehow I couldn't quite formulate it properly myself. Thanks.